# Docusign email localization when setting SupportedLanguage = "fr"

Tags: email, localization, docusignapi

I want to customize the docusign emails that are sent to the participants.
I'm sending the below:

```
SupportedLanguage = "fr"
```

as part of the Signer in the api call to create envelope. The "Enable custom email and language for each recipient" is checked, however the email is still showing up in English. I've learned that the user needs to set their locale settings to that language in order to receive the email in a different language. Can you help me with the specifics of how this needs to be set? Is it in the docusign account for the consumer or the user's machine? What else am I missing here?

Comment: can someone plz answer this?

Answer (score 0):

The above line of code can be used to have the email for a specific recipient sent in French.

However, that only works if the person in question did not already decide to use DocuSign with some other language.
In other words - they can override your choice if they have their own DocuSign account and not also have it set to French.

> Is it in the docusign account for the consumer or the user's machine?

It only depends on if the user in question is a member of any DocuSign account, i.e. they have credentials to DocuSign.

[This blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/the-trenches-recipient-email-languages) can be useful.